# Split a data frame by the last column programmatically

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to `split` a data frame, with an arbitrary number of columns, by the *last* column, without providing a column name or number. Something like [imaginary code land]:

```
d <- split(MY_DATA, ncol(MYDATA))
```

A sample data set might be something like:

```
pepsi  1
dr_pep 2
coke   1
```

Where our data set has no headers, by the last column would represent a desired grouping like the following:

```
dr_pep 2 --> group 2

pepsi  1  --> group 1
coke   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text = 'pepsi  1
dr_pep 2
coke   1', header=F)

split(df, df[,ncol(df)])
```